# Get URL Params before server Next js render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get the params in a url redirected from the Spotify api, ex: http//link.com/?code=examplecode
How can I get the value of code before it renders so I can redirect it and pass the code value to another page?

Comment: You should create a next api then call that route... then just create a rewrite or redirect to your homepage or whatever you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out and I'll leave it here in case someone needs it.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

const router = useRouter();
const code = router.query.code;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to import `useRouter` :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

and inside of your component write this:

```
const { query } = useRouter();
```

Answer (score 0):

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const App=()=>{
const query  = useRouter();

console.log(query)  //to view the params

return(
`enter code here`
);
}

Answer (score 0):

**For someone trying to use Routers using dynamic routing in NextJs**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const {query} =useRouter();

const id=query.[your file name];
```

For example:

If your structure has a route Profile and under that you have [username.js].So your code will be like this:

```
const id=query.username;
```